# "If not exists" using OBJECT_ID() doesn't work for views and triggers. why?

Tags: sql-server, trigger, view

For tables I can implement "if not exists" and "if exists" as folows:

```
--if table exists - drop
If OBJECT_ID('A','U') is not null
Drop Table [A]
--if table not exists - Create
If OBJECT_ID('A','U') is null
Create Table A([key] varchar(20), [value] varchar(max))
```

but it is not quite working the same on views and triggers

I can do:

```
-- if exists - drop
If OBJECT_ID('VA','V') is not null
Drop view [VA]
```

but when I'm trying the oposite:

```
-- if not exists - create
If OBJECT_ID('VA','V') is null
Create view [VA] as Select * from [A]
```

I'm Getting the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'view'

And the same is with triggers. when I do:

```
-- if not exists - create
If OBJECT_ID('Trigger_A_ins','TR') is null
Create trigger [Trigger_A_ins] On [A] instead of insert As 
   insert into A select * from inserted
```

I'm getting error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'trigger'

But:

```
-- if exists - drop
If OBJECT_ID('Trigger_A_ins','TR') is not null
Drop Trigger Trigger_A_ins
```

is working.

Did I missed anything?

Can anyone explain this difference between tables to triggers and views?

**Note:** I'm using sql server 2012

Comment: While it doesn't help you on 2012, for those on 2016+: you can now use `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS` (similar for tables, views, etc.).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Referencing the documentation from [CREATE VIEW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) under REMARKS:

> The CREATE VIEW must be the first statement in a query batch.

Referencing the documentation from [CREATE TRIGGER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> CREATE TRIGGER must be the first statement in the batch and can apply
>   to only one table.

For `VIEWS` and `TRIGGERS`, I think you'll have to check for the existence of the object and drop in one batch and create them in another batch separated by a `GO`

Example:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE [name] = '[dbo].[trg]' AND [type] = 'TR')
      DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[trg] ON [dbo].[tbl]
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg] ON [dbo].[tbl] 
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
   //
END
GO
```

Answer (score 7):

If you still need this on the same batch, you can use dynamic SQL.

```
If OBJECT_ID('vTest','V') is not null
    DROP VIEW vTest

EXEC('CREATE VIEW vTest AS SELECT TOP 1 * FROM SomeTable')
```